# Getting value of object id from new method to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with getting value of found id from new method to create.

New method:

```
def new
  @vacation = Vacation.new
  @vacation.person = @person
end
```

Result of @person:

```
#<id: 1, first_name: ... >
```

@vacation.person is also good.
For now all is well. But after this, when I fill form and click submit:

```
def create
  @vacation = Vacation.new(vacation_params)
end
```

Result:

```
#<Vacation id: ..., person_id: nil >
```

But now @person is nil and also @vacation.person is nil. I don't have idea how to send value of id to create method.

Method to find id.

```
before_action :set_person

private

def set_person
  @person = Person.find(params[:id]) unless params[:id].blank?
end
```

vacation_params:

```
def vacation_params
  params.require(:vacation).permit(:start_at, :end_at, :free, :reason, :person_id, :accepted)
end
```

Comment: Can you show us your form(in the view).

Comment: If you don't have it in the form it won't be posted, so either have a hidden field in the form or add the person in the create method.

Comment: @j-dexx thank you for your help.

Comment: @ŁukaszKorol You're welcome, have a good weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem, by adding hidden field.

```
= f.input :person_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: @person.id}
```